# Change background color of whole page on click at main div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I try to change the background color of my whole page, on click on my div with id `main`. Here is [my code](http://jsfiddle.net/22m0to5o/):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var color = 1;
            
    $('#main').click(function(){
        if (color == 1)   {
            $(this).css("background-color", "green");
            color = 2;
        } else if (color == 2) {
            $(this).css("background-color", "black");
            color = 1;
        }                 
    });
});
```

```css
#admin_div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #D9D9D9;
    z-index: 1;
}   

h1 { 
  margin-left: 15px; 
}

#main {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
    <div id="admin_div">  
      <h1>Admin Panel</h1>
   </div>
</div>
```

But the background color is also changing if i click on another element than main. I think it is because everything is inside the main div.

Comment: Consider to use relevant indentation, your code is unreadable... Now in click handler, pass event and check for `if(event.target !== this) return;`

Comment: @EdwardBlack Is requirement to change `#main` background color as well ?

Comment: It should only change #main background color

Comment: @EdwardBlack What result is not being returned by `js` at Question ?

Comment: But `$(this)` refers to `#main` in click handler. Whole page would be `$('body')`...  And i misunderstood you expected behaviour, your issue has nothing to do with `if(event.target !== this)`, this is what happen usually when i'm trying to understand question with unreadable code... ;)

Comment: @A.Wolff _"It should only change #main background color"_ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33914056/change-background-color-of-whole-page-on-click-at-main-wrap-div#comment55589810_33914056 ?

Comment: @guest271314 OK, i'm completly lost to understand question... ;) No i guess it is because the `#admin_div` has position absolute and background set. Again, i'm copmletly lost...

Comment: @A. Wolff, stop confusing me pls. Can you explain how my code is "unreadable"? Maybe you should reinstall your browser, because i can read it with no problem.

Comment: @EdwardBlack This is correctly indented code: http://jsfiddle.net/22m0to5o/2/   Isn't it more readable§?!  BTW, you said: `I try to change the background color of my whole page` & then: `It should only change #main background color`. So who is confusing people???

Comment: @A. Wollf, thats much more complicated to read then my code. You can tell way easier and faster whats happening if you look at my code, instead of yours, but okay...

Comment: @EdwardBlack There is some rules regarding indentation, you aren't following any here...

Comment: @A.Wolff, oh do i have to go to jail now because i broke the "rules"? My code is still much easier to read then yours, so i don't give a f

Comment: @EdwardBlack Who cares, GL!...

Comment: Who cares about these stupid rules which makes code unnecessary complicated? Every beginner will understand much faster whats happening if he looks at my code, then at yours.

Comment: @EdwardBlack https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ABhDiXbUaBE

Comment: You probably try to look more intelligent to others if you make your code much more complicated then it actually is

Comment: @EdwardBlack `You probably try to look more intelligent to others if you make your code much more complicated then it actually is` You make my day, really. Thx

Comment: I will never understand why people make things more complicated then necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clicking on red color (target div) everything work like exprected

http://jsfiddle.net/22m0to5o/1/

```
var color = 1;

$('#main').click(function (event) {

    if (event.target !== this) return;

    if (color == 1) 
    {
        $('body').css("background-color", "green");
        color = 2;
    } 
    if (color == 2) 
    {
        $('body').css("background-color", "black");
        color = 1;
    }

});
```

Comment: `if(event.target !== this) return;`
Solved my problem. Thx.

Comment: Select this as the answer please

Comment: I don't like your coding style tho

Comment: It's not my coding style in fiddle and in answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a kind of useless piece of JavaScript code, although I suppose it could be useful for something. Whether this is just a waste of time or not, I will present you with the code straightaway, that will allow you to dynamically change the background color of the page.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
function changeBGC(color){
document.bgColor = color;
}
//-->
</script>
```

I think it is quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change the background color of the whole page, just rewrite the jquery code. change $(this) to $('body').

```
 <script>
$(document).ready
(
    function()
    {
        var color = 1;

        $('#main').click
        (
            function()
            {
                if (color == 1)
                {
                    $('body').css("background-color", "green");
                    color = 2;
                } 
                else if (color == 2)
                {
                    $('body').css("background-color", "black");
                    color = 1;  
                }

            }
        );

    }
);
</script>
```